# Generalization of the Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

The classic Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem states that
$$
\sup_{t}|F_{n}(t) - F(t)| \longrightarrow_{a.s.} 0
$$
where $F_{n}(t)$ is the empirical cdf.

Looking at the proof of the theorem, it seems to me like it only uses the fact that
$F_{n}(x) \longrightarrow_{a.s.} F(x)$ for each fixed $x$, and that 
both $F_{n}(x)$ and $F(x)$ are monotonic with $0\leq F(x) \leq 1$
and $0 \leq F_{n}(x) \leq 1$.

My first question is that if, in general, we have an estimated function $G_{n}(t)$
such that $G_{n}(t) \longrightarrow_{a.s.} G(t)$ for each fixed $t$ with 
$G(t)$ monotonic and $|G(t)| \leq K$, is it true that
$$
\sup_{t}|G_{n}(t) - G(t)| \longrightarrow_{a.s.} 0?
$$

Another question I have is if the above can be generalized to some extent.
That is, if, we have an estimated function $G_{n}(t)$
such that $G_{n}(t) \longrightarrow_{a.s.} G(t)$ for each fixed $t$ with 
$G(t)$ continuous and $|G(t)| \leq K$ for $t \in [a,b]$, is it true that
$$
\sup_{t \in [a,b]}|G_{n}(t) - G(t)| \longrightarrow_{a.s.} 0?
$$
where $a < b$ are finite numbers.